# Framework error: code: 60 reason: SSL certificate problem: unable to get local issuer certificate in solaris 11.3

Tags: solaris

pkg set-publisher: The origin URIs for 'solarisstudio' do not appear to point to a valid pkg repository.
Please verify the repository's location and the client's network configuration.
Additional details:

Unable to contact valid package repository: https://pkg.oracle.com/solarisstudio/release
Encountered the following error(s):
Transport errors encountered when trying to contact repository.
Reported the following errors:
Framework error: code: 60 reason: SSL certificate problem: unable to get local issuer certificate
URL: 'https://pkg.oracle.com/solarisstudio/release'

Answer (score 0):

1.Make sure that ca-certificates service is running on solaris
svcs -xv
if not try starting using the below commands
svcadm disable svc:/system/ca-certificates:default
svcadm enable svc:/system/ca-certificates:default
Make sure that the below permission is set for all the certificates

If the above solution doesnot work
2. Take backup of all the certificates under /etc/certs/CA.  Check for the corrupted certificates,  by moving the certificates one by one to /etc/certs/CA in the location and starting ca-certificate service. The point when the service doesn't start is the certificate which is corrupted.
Make sure that the certificates in the location have below permissions
sudo chown root:sys /etc/certs/CA/*.pem